# Javascript ES6 split object array into two different object subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, reduce

I have an array of objects or json called `obj.credits: []` that contains about 50 credit objects. Each credit object has a `cast_id` field that is either null or not null

I want to completely filter all objects having null `cast_id` into a subarray `obj.credits.crew: []` and all objects having not null `cast_id` into another subarray `obj.credits.cast: []`.

After that `obj.credits` should only contain keys `cast` and `crew`.

The following is not working. it creates subarrays but does not delete the original array objects

```
 obj.credits.cast = obj.credits.filter(credit => credit.cast_id != null)
 obj.credits.crew = obj.credits.filter(credit => credit.cast_id == null)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I am not sure how an array would have two properties added to it. Seems a bit weird, why not create a new object?

Comment: by "not working" I mean it creates two subarrays but the original array items are not removed. suppose there are 50 objects in total, 25 have null `cast_id` and other 25 have not null `cast_id`

Comment: BECAUSE IT IS AN ARRAY, NOT AN OBJECT. If you do not want the array, replace it with an object.

Comment: filter will not alter the original array. Also you cannot do newArray.x = 123; where newArray is an array.

Comment: You can create new separate arrays or create a different object with crew and cast properties. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is the fact you are acting like an Array is an Object. You are just adding properties to your array. If you want it to be an object, you need to rethink how you are doing this.

So you want a final output of an object with two properties that contain arrays, so replace obj.credits with an object.

```
obj.credits = obj.credits.reduce((acc, credit) => {
  if (credit.cast_id != null) acc.cast.push(credit);
  else acc.crew.push(credit);
  return acc;
}, { cast: [], crew: [] });
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj.credits` is an array. You can't add **cast** and **crew** properties into this.
So you can create 2 separate sub-arrays -

```
let cast = obj.credits.filter(credit => credit.cast_id != null)
let crew = obj.credits.filter(credit => credit.cast_id == null)
```

Then clear the `obj.credits` array and initialize it as an object. Then add these sub-arrays as properties.

```
obj.credits = {};
obj.credits = {cast, crew};
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, you do not have to traverse the array twice just to separate cast from crew.

```
const cast = [];
const crew = [];
for (const item of obj.credits){
  if (!item) continue;
  if (item.cast_id) cast.push(item);
  else crew.push(item);
}
obj.credits.cast = cast;
obj.credits.crew = crew;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very easy question to understand.
The long way around this (that will work) is to initialise two new arrays (credits.crew and credits.cast), loop through your main array checking the key if it is null or not and then adding that record to one of the new arrays.
This assumes you have the write methods on the object to get its value.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all iterable elements from a list, set its length to zero. Example below.

```js
let obj = {}
obj.credits = [
  {cast_id: 1},
  {cast_id: 2},
  {cast_id: null}
]
obj.credits.cast = obj.credits.filter(credit => credit.cast_id != null)
obj.credits.crew = obj.credits.filter(credit => credit.cast_id == null)

// remove all elements from `credits` property of `obj`
obj.credits.length = 0

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj), '<br>')
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj.credits), '<br>')
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj.credits.cast), '<br>')
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj.credits.crew))
```